# How to clear the program settings for windows mobile when uninstalling this app?

Tags: windows-mobile

I use windows mobile 2005, visual studio 2008, c++ smart device application.

I use getprofilestring, writeprofilestring (and similar ones) to work with settings. I use .cab file for app installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a separate setup project and to specify correctly all the ne registry paths.